# (Almost) barebones Ubuntu installation

Tags: unity, 14.10

All I need is Ubuntu and Unity, no other apps, not even Software Center. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always install the from the minimal image.  [Ubuntu Minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)